# sending one by one message through python over tcp protocol?

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to send same message 10 times through python over tcp protocol. 
here is python code.

```
import socket
import sys
import random

HOST = '192.168.1.29'   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 55555 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(1)
print 'Socket now listening at',HOST, PORT
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
count = 0;
while 1:
    if (count > 9):
        break
    else:
        count = count + 1
        data  = ("hello world....!")
        conn.send(data)
        print "",data
    if data == "exit":
        break

conn.close()
s.close()
```

As per code, Here i am trying to send "hello world" 10 times to far end as a separate message. In short each packet should contain only one time "hello world". but in my surprise, First packet contains one hello world message,but second packet contains 9 times hello world message. will you please let me know why it is happening? Is there any bug in code? if its not the way then how to send 10 different packets each containing one time hello world through python over tcp ?

Comment: What is conn in your code?

Comment: conn, addr = s.accept()

Comment: [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is a stream-based protocol, use [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) if you want to send individual packets. If you insist on TCP, you'll need to devise a way to differentiate your individual messages when sending and receiving them - for simple strings ye olde [null termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) should be more than enough.

Comment: Please post the full example, we're missing what ``conn`` is and which modules you're using. When you're trying to implement a line based protocol, you may need to call something like ``conn.flush()`` after each line to actually send the data, which may be buffered.

Comment: @allo, i updated full code. Here I am trying to send "hello world", 10 times to connected socket in seperate packet. but first packet it will send normally with single hello world, but 2nd packet is combinig of nine hello word and fin + ack request also. will you please review it and let me know where is my mistake?

Comment: The indentation of the code you've posted is not correct. (E.g., does `count = count + 1` belong to the `else` or to `while 1`?) Please fix it, otherwise it's not possible to tell what the actual mistake in the code is.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I removed indentation and updated the code with summary. But still its not working as per my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks all to give prompt reply. i find answer of my question. At one far end (sender) Tcp stack stores the data into the buffer and wait till buffer will be full and time out to send message in one packet. So after one message, tcp stack should have to be timed out. If it doesnt time out then tcp stack will combine with next messages. Like before i was facing the problem. Here i am sending different four messages 10 times. in previous example hello world you can remove function call and prefix data = hello world it.

Here is code and its working fine. Verified it through wireshark.

```
import socket
import sys
import random
import time

HOST = '192.168.1.29'   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 55555 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(1)
print 'Socket now listening at',HOST, PORT
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
count = 1;

var = 0
def read_data(var):
    if var == 1:
        data = "1 hi"
        return data 
    elif var == 2:
        data = "2 how are you"
        return data 
    elif var == 3:
        data = "3 where are you?"
        return data 
    else:
        data = "4 what are you doing?"
        return data


while 1:
    if(count < 10):
        count = count + 1
        var = random.randint(1,4)
        read_data(var);
        msg = read_data(var);
        conn.send(msg)
        print "",msg
        time.sleep(5)
    elif(count==10):
        data = "exit"
        conn.send(data)
        print "",data
        time.sleep(5) 
        break   
    else: 
        break


conn.close()
s.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand, you want to send data trough TCP. I use this code to send string via sockets

Send

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.2" #IP of the sender
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print "MSG:" + data
```

Receive

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "192.168.1.1" #IP of the receiver
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
while True:
    try:
            data = str("Hello World!")
            print len(data)
            sock.sendto(data, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
```

Comment: yeah. But its for udp. will you please help me out for tcp.?